# Puppeteer - How to Check If an Element's Display Property Has Changed?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a script that automates certain actions on a website that offers participation in various online events.

The script navigates to the event selection page, and enters each event using the information provided in a text file. The script is expected to enter each event only once. To prevent duplicate entries, I am trying to check for a "has-entered" class in the HTML that indicates whether an event has already been entered.

Here's an example of how the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="st_style_page 123-entered already-entered-float" style="display:none;">
</div>
```

When an event has not been entered, the "display" property for this class is set to "none". However, once the event is entered, the "display:none" property disappears.

I tried to write a function to check the visibility of this "has-entered" element using Puppeteer's page.$(selector) and elementHandle.boundingBox(), but it's throwing an error. Here's what that function looks like:

```
const isVisible = async (page, selector) => {
  const elementHandle = await page.$(selector);
  if (elementHandle) {
    const boundingBox = await elementHandle.boundingBox();
    return boundingBox !== null;
  } else {
    return false;  // If no element matches the selector, we assume that it's not visible
  }
};
```

However, this keeps throwing an error and I'm unable to figure out why. The rest of my script functions as expected. Here's a simplified version of the script:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');

const isVisible = async (page, selector) => {
  const elementHandle = await page.$(selector);
  if (elementHandle) {
    const boundingBox = await elementHandle.boundingBox();
    return boundingBox !== null;
  } else {
    return false;  // If no element matches the selector, we assume that it's not visible
  }
};

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });  
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    await page.goto('https://website.com/page');  // Go to the event selection page
    
    // Execute some logic to log in and reach the event list page
    // Omitted for brevity...

    // Extracting event data
    const eventElements = await page.$$('.event_class');
    const eventData = await Promise.all(eventElements.map(async (eventElement) => {
      const eventId = await eventElement.$eval('[onclick]', node => node.getAttribute('onclick').match(/\d+/)[0]);
      return { eventElement, eventId };
    }));

    console.log("Filtering events and entering ones that are not entered yet");
    for (const { eventId } of eventData) {
      // This is the problematic part, the isVisible check fails
      if (await isVisible(page, `#${eventId}-entered`)) {
        console.log("Event entered already for " + eventId);
        continue;
      }

      // If not entered yet, enter the event
      // ... enter event logic here ...
    }             

  } catch (error) {
    console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
  } finally {
    console.log("Closing browser");
    await browser.close();
  }

})();
```

My question is, how can I properly check if the "has-entered" class is visible (i.e., the "display:none" property has been removed), and if so, skip entering that event?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this, using my puppeteer wrapper library
https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai
[Documentation](https://wix-incubator.github.io/bubanai/modules/src.html)

You can try to use several functions, like

```js
import { waitToBeVisible } from 'bubanai-ng';

await waitToBeVisible(page, '#${eventId}-entered');
```

or

```js
import { waitForElementToBeInViewport } from 'bubanai-ng';

await waitForElementToBeInViewport(page, '#${eventId}-entered');
```

or

```js
import { waitForConditionToBeFalsy, getProperty } from 'bubanai-ng';

await waitForConditionToBeFalsy(() => getProperty('style', page, '#${eventId}-entered').then((p) =>
      p.toString().includes('display:none'));
```